# How to include filter effects for image in .Net MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, image, filter, maui

I need to apply filter effects like Chrome, Cold, Warm effects in MAUI image control. Is there any reference or examples available for it?

I tried to use PlatformBehavior and apply filters for native views but no success.

Comment: 1. May I know on what platform you are targeting to? 2. You said you tried to use PlatformBehavior and apply filters for native views but no success. Can you help add that to your post? 3. According to [Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/image), it seems there's no filter effects for the image control.

Comment: Hello, if you want to apply a color filter on image, you may refer to [SkiaSharp color filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/effects/color-filters). You could design your own color matrix.